# Ubuntu 13.04 put resolution at 1024x768

Tags: unity, nvidia, 13.04, display, resolution

After the installation of Ubuntu 13.04, I have the resolution at 1024x768 instead of 1280x800, and even after switching all the possible drivers in Settings, the situation doesn't change. Plus, this problem makes it impossible to see the launcher and all the Unity/Compiz things. If I solve this with the dconf command I could try to fix this, but I cannot at 1024, I need the 1280x800 resolution.

My computer:

- Sony Vaio FZ21M
- Intel Ccore 2 Duo
- NVidia GeForce 8400M GT

Comment: Please the content of the files _xorg.conf_ and _Xorg.0.log_ plus the output of _xrandr_ _lshw_ and _lspci -vvnnk_ (video portions only, please).